# Receiving data via stdin and storing as a variable/array

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

I am trying to receive data via stdin which I have working:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readStream = process.stdin;

readStream.pause();
readStream.setEncoding('utf8');

readStream.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  });
readStream.resume();
```

Now what I need to do is store it as a variable so I can do some calculations before I return it via stdout.

Every time I try to so anything with it, like push certain data to an array it repeats the data until the stdin has finished, and I cant access it after it has finished.  I cant find any resources online to help me.

Comment: Is using node.js a requirement?

Comment: I only have experience with JavaScript and would like to keep it as close to what I know as possible.

Comment: Yes, the requirement is possible using JavaScript available at browser. Are you trying to meet requirement using only node.js?

Comment: Using node is definitely preferable, but I am open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReadableStream` to process asynchronous tasks. Call `.getReader()` of `ReadableStream` instance to get an object which has a `.read()` method which when called returns an object having `value` and `done` properties. The controller passed to the constructor can queue tasks to be performed, the call to `read()` reads the enqueued data and sets the data at `value` property.

```js
let n = 0;
let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const results = [];

let readableStream = new ReadableStream({
  pull(controller) {
    if (n < letters.length) controller.enqueue(letters[n++])
    else controller.close();
  }
});

let reader = readableStream.getReader();

let processStream = ({value, done}) => {
  if (done) return reader.closed.then(() => results);
  console.log(value);
  // do stuff
  let next = new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(() => {results.push(value); resolve()}
    , Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200))
  );
  return next.then(() => reader.read())
         .then(data => processStream(data));
}

reader.read()
.then(data => processStream(data))
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

You can also pipe the `ReadableStream` and `.pipeTo()` method of the instance to pipe the enqueued data to a `WritableStream` instance, where tasks can be performed at both read and write portions of the stream.

```js
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

let RSController = class {
  constructor(input) {
    this.input = input;
    this.n = 0;
  }
  async pull(controller) {
    if (this.n < this.input.length) {
      let curr = await this.handleData(this.input[this.n]);
      ++this.n;
      controller.enqueue(curr);
    } else {
      this.n = 0;
      controller.close();
    }
  }
  cancel(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  handleData(data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // do stuff
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(data)
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 750))
    })
  }
}

let WSController = class {
  constructor(arr = []) {
    this.results = arr;
  }
  write(data) {
    let dataUp = data.toUpperCase();
    console.log(data, dataUp);
    this.results.push([data, dataUp]);
  }
  close() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.results, null, 2));
  }
  abort(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

let rscontroller = new RSController(letters);

let readableStream = new ReadableStream(rscontroller);

let wscontroller = new WSController([]);

let writableStream = new WritableStream(wscontroller);

readableStream
.pipeTo(writableStream);
```