# How to send ArrayBuffer in json from js client to nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send data of type ArrayBuffer in json to my server using socket.io like this:

```
socket.emit('record', {
       name: myUsername + '.wav',
       data: data //arraybuffer
 });
```

On server side, when i receive 'record' event in socket, I get the *data* from JSON and save it in *name* file like this:

```
socket.on('record', function(message){
      var fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter(message.name, {
        channels: 1,
        sampleRate: 48000,
        bitDepth: 16
        });
      message.data.pipe(fileWriter);
    });
```

I am using *require('wav')* & *require('stream')* package from npm. The problem is that my server crashes on `message.data.pipe(fileWriter);` with this error:

```
TypeError: message.data.pipe is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't i send ArrayBuffer like this in socket.io?

Comment: Call `.pipe()`  chained to the stream instance, not the `ArrayBuffer` `message.data`

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an `ArrayBuffer`, not a `ReadableStream`. Enqueue `data` to be read by a `ReadableStream`, passed to a `WritableStream` or `TransformStream`, for example using `.pipeThrough()`, see [Receiving data via stdin and storing as a variable/array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427642/receiving-data-via-stdin-and-storing-as-a-variable-array/45428763#45428763).

Comment: I am sorry, but i didn't understand. How can i convert my ArrayBuffer to stream instance? Can you point me to exact code? Also, am i supposed to  convert it on client-side or server-side after receiving the data?

Comment: You cannot.  Pass the array buffer to the stream instance `.pipe()` method

Comment: There is no way i can convert array buffer to stream?

Comment: No. Pass the array buffer to a readable, writable or transform stream. You are trying to read or write the contents of the array buffer, yes?

Comment: Have not tried nodejs streams implementation. The gist is to pass the data to a stream instance for reading, writing or both; where you define the read/write tasks to be performed - not to convert the data itself to a reader or writer. See https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/, https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook

Comment: @QandeelAbbasi Yes, that appears to be what you are trying to achieve using nodejs. You may need to pass the `ArrayBuffer` to a `TypedArray` to iterate the `TypedArray` using the same pattern.

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try