# How to properly build a multi-dimensional update-object/array and patch it over an existing multi-dimensional object? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, diff, javascript-objects

I have two applications, the first reads data from memory and then sends this data to the second application, which always holds an object with the latest data.

Currently, I read all the data in application one and send the complete json object to application 2. To make this more efficient, I'd like to only send what has updated and then in application 2, apply these changes.

I've tried sevaral things over the weekend but I can't decide how to properly do it.

Right now, while reading the data from memory (with a function running every 30ms), I check if the values are different from what they were, just before I read them. If so, put them into an update object or array.

Which currently looks like this:

```
let globalData = {};
let updateList = {};

function readThingsFromMemory() {
  updateList = {};

  for ( ... ) {
    [read memory]
    setData(... , ..., ...);
  }
}

function setData(...1, ...2, ...3) {
  if (globalData[...1][...2] != ...3) {
    if (updateList[...1] === undefined) {
      updateList[...1] = {};
    }
    updateList[...1][...2] = ...3;
  }
  globalData[...1][...2] = ...3;
}

setInterval(() => {
  readThingsFromMemory();

  // Send updateList to application 2 if updateList != empty
}, 30);
```

This just seems to me like a weird way and I feel like this could be a lot cleaner and maybe even easier.

Would it even be a good idea to first, create a globalData object from readThingsFromMemory() and after that, loop over that object and determine the differences? Or is it better to do this while reading the memory?

**Side notes: Using memoryjs to read from memory and using websockets to send the data to application 2. Also note: The data is an object of objects, not just a plain object.**

Comment: Maybe compare current data with the old one and generate diff-patches? Try https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch

Comment: So you mean, keep a global object and then in readThingsFromMemory() build a new object and AFTER that, compare these two? That was one of my questions: Isnt that worse than comparing each entry while reading them from memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) to get/apply the delta of two states.

```js
const prevGrades = [{ name: "Sam", grade: 84 }, { name: "Jack", grade: 93 }, { name: "Will", grade: 64 }, { name: "Ron", grade: 82 }, { name: "Sara", grade: 95 }, { name: "Martha", grade: 71 }];

const currentGrades = [{ name: "Sam", grade: 84 }, { name: "Jack", grade: 93 }, { name: "Oscar", grade: 74 }, { name: "Ron", grade: 82 }, { name: "Sara", grade: 95 }, { name: "Martha", grade: 71 }];

const delta = jsondiffpatch.diff(prevGrades, currentGrades);

console.log("delta:", delta);

const lastSavedState = [{ name: "Sam", grade: 84 }, { name: "Jack", grade: 93 }, { name: "Will", grade: 64 }, { name: "Ron", grade: 82 }, { name: "Sara", grade: 95 }, { name: "Martha", grade: 71 }];

const updatedState = jsondiffpatch.patch(lastSavedState, delta);

console.log("updatedState: ", updatedState);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsondiffpatch/0.2.5/jsondiffpatch-full.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is `"_t": "a"` at first `console.log()` call?

Comment: According to the docs `"_t": "a", // indicates this node is an array (not an object)"`

Comment: So all answers for now suggest to 1. keep a global object and 2. first create a complete new object by reading through memory and THEN compare them. So I this that is not worse than checking if something has updates WHILE reading through the memory?

Comment: @SVARTBERG _"So I this that is not worse than checking if something has updates WHILE reading through the memory?"_ You can use a `TransformStream` to read and write data as a stream, e.g., see [Receiving data via stdin and storing as a variable/array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427642/receiving-data-via-stdin-and-storing-as-a-variable-array/). Still not certain what issue is with code at Question?

Comment: If you want to send just the changes, you'll have to save the current state on both applications (memory/db/files/whatever...). Compare the new state with old, generate a diff, send the diff, patch. The other option is to send the new state.

Comment: What I mean is, that I have a for-loop for reading data from memory like reading some value from 0x1, some other vlaue from 0x2 and so on ... My thoughts were: Isnt it better to compare each value to the current ones, while reading them from memory and before overwriting them in the global object. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SVARTBERG - you can use a streaming diff, such as [json-patch-diff-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff-patch-stream) or [diff-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff-stream). I haven't used any of them, so I don't know how good they work.

Comment: Alright but does it even matter if I first read through memory and compare afterwards or if I do comparison while reading the specific values?

Comment: Diffing while reading should be faster. However, it's a big "should". It depends on the size of the data, the algorithm used, and many other factors. Try and profile it, and you'll know.

Comment: For the fact that the data is not that much (~ an object with max. 32 child-object, each holding max. 6 properties) i will just stay with comparing after I read everything from mem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.filter` to find changes. Keep in mind that value-based equality only works with primitives.

```
const memoryData = {
  a: 10,
  b: 12
}

const globalData = {
  a: 11,
  b: 12
}
//find only differences in app 1
const changedEntries = Object.entries(memoryData).filter(([key, val]) => {
  return globalData[key] !== memoryData[key]
})
console.log(changedEntries) //[ [ 'a', 10 ] ]

//send changedEntries to app 2 and patch over global data
const = changedEntries.forEach(([key, val]) => {
  globalData[key] = val
})

console.log(globalData) //{ a: 10, b: 12 }
```

Comment: You can kinda read from my example, I rather have an object of objects, where I also need to look if objects were deleted etc.

Comment: @SVARTBERG You should clarify that and change your question's title. I thought you were just looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: Done, sry. //2short